# Resize image before getting data from URL : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image

I am presenting some photos into a collectionView. I am getting some URL's from the server and I do a request with KingFisher. My problem is that the URLs I have include images with more than 2000x1000 pixels. Can I avoid downloading such big photos and instead requesting a smaller version of that image? I don't want to download and then resize cause that will not speed things up. Thanks.

My code :

```
self.image.kf.setImage(with: URL(string:imageUrl)!, placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"), options: nil, progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
print(totalSize)
            }, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: That would only be possible if it were supported by your server.

Comment: The server would need to support image resizing.  You cannot do that on the client alone.